# ApacheでPHPのスクリプトが実行されず、コードが表示される

Tags: php, apache

ApacheでPHPを動作させたいのですが、phpのURLにアクセスしてもコードが表示されてしまします
Linuxは初心者です。

<s>phpinfoは表示でき、</s>コマンドラインでphpは動作します。

いろいろ調べて
`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`に

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

AddHandler php7-script .php
```

等を書き込み`service httpd restart`
試しましたがかわらずコードが表示されました。
苦戦しています、アドバイスお願いします。

試したコード
test.php

```
<?php
    echo "test php";
?>
```

バージョン

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov  1 2017 18:47:16

$ php -v
PHP 7.0.27 (cli) (built: Jan 25 2018 22:40:53) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

追記
やりなおしてみるとphpinfoの表示に失敗しました
参考にしているマニュアル
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

Comment: phpはどうやってインストールしました？あと可能であればサーバの環境も追記ください。……なんとなく`LoadModule`で`php7_module`が読み込まれていない気もしなくも無いです。

Comment: サーバはAWSのEC2上に、下のチュートリアルを参考にたてました
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html
ただ、phpinfoを表示する部分をやりなおすと、phpinfoが正常に表示されず下のコードが表示されてしまいました。
<?php phpinfo(); ?>